# Find points inside a closed area

Tags: unity, algorithm, geometry, grid

I have a 2D rectangular grid (100x100) with 3 types of cell (Empty, Base and Outline). I need to find cells inside the territory formed by Base and Outline cells.

For example, in this scheme:

[image]

I need to find the yellow cells.

The same algorithm, but with hexagonal grid, was implemented in the game in this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/6zyMHnBM5x8.

Any help on how to achieve that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at the second answer; the accepted answer tells you what to do, in a rough way. The second answer provides actual detail in regards to what you should do to create this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call this function only when needed, to save on CPU cycle.

Based on the video you linked, there must be a mechanism that determines the first outline cell, the last one, and the cell path in the grid. You need to keep track of the cursor status, in particular we need to know whether the outline cells have became a closed shape along with the base line.

**Phase 1 - Reducing the working area**
Every time a cell path is completed, we compute the AABB vertex coordinates enclosing the outline cells along with the base cell blobs our outline is tangent with. This way we can reduce the grid sector affected by an outline adjunction in the set.

For example, in your image (assuming `(0,0)` as top leftmost corner), we find the rectangle from `(5,2)` to `(14,10)` to contain the outline cells; and the rectangle with vertices `(4,5)` and `(11,12)` to be the one containing the base cells. Then, the area of interest will be from `(4,2)` to `(14,12)` since the floodfill will certainly happen within this area of the grid (this reduces complexity slightly).

**Phase 2 - Find the enclosed blob**
Now you have a subgrid with a border-like shape and two possible surface: the inner and the outer ones. It's easy to determine the one we are interested in: every single cell belongs either to the first or the second one; also, cells lying on the subgrid borders will belong to the outer surface, unless there were not even one of those, which means there is one only, inner surface (and we were looking right for this one).

Answer (score -2):

You should use a hunt and eliminate type algorithm.

Basically, you search through the whole grod until you find an empty space (or something that you search for), then use floodfill and mark every positiom the fill reaches. Continue searching until you find an unmarked empty cell. You have to repeat this until the search reaches the end of the map.